# converting to tail recursion

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion

Consider a function g(x):

```
g(x) = x == 0 ? 0 : g(g(x - 1))
```

I don't think this is tail recursive, since the call to g(x) can be broken down into two parts:

```
let y = g(x - 1);
return g(y);
```

how to convert this to tail recursion?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried nothing. yes this is my homework.

Comment: Ha. Your professor has a sense of humor. Try evaluating function g on a few values. What do you notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**continuation-passing style**

You can convert from direct style to [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) -

```
g'(x,return) =
  x == 0
    ? return(0)
    : g'(x - 1, x' =>        # tail
        g'(x', return))      # tail
```

Now write `g` to call `g'` with the default continuation -

```
g(x) = g'(x, x' => x')
```

Depending on the language you use, you may have to rename `return` to something else. `k` is a popular choice.

**another example**

We can see this technique applied to other problems like `fib` -

```
# direct style
fib(x) =
  x < 2
    ? x
    : fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2) # "+" has tail position; not fib
```

```
# continuation-passing style
fib'(x, return) =
  x < 2
    ? return(x)
    : fib'(x - 1, x' =>       # tail| first compute x - 1
        fib(x - 2, x'' =>     # tail| then compute x - 2
          return(x' + x'')))  # tail| then return sum

fib(x) = fib'(x, z => z)
```

**other uses**

Continuation-passing style is useful in other ways too. For example, it can be used to provide branching or early-exit behavior in this `search` program -

```
search(t, index, match, ifFound, notFound) =
  i >= length(t)
    ? notFound()
    : t[index] == match
        ? ifFound(index)
        : search(t, index + 1, match, ifFound, notFound)
```

We can call `search` with continuations for each possible outcome -

```
search(["bird", "cat", "dog"],
  0,
  "cat",
  matchedIndex => print("found at: " + matchedIndex),
  () => print("not found")
)
```

**how to**

> A function written in continuation-passing style takes **an extra argument**: an explicit "continuation"; i.e., a function of one argument — <sub>[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)</sub>

```ml
(* direct style *)
add(a, b) = ...

(* continuation-passing style takes extra argument *)
add(a, b, k) = ...
```

> When the CPS function has computed its result value, it **"returns" it by calling the continuation function** with this value as the argument.

```ml
(* direct style *)
add(a, b) =
  a + b

(* continuation-passing style "returns" by calling continuation *)
add(a, b, k) =
  k(a + b)         (* call k with the return value *)
```

> That means that when invoking a CPS function, the calling function is required to supply a procedure to be invoked with the subroutine's "return" value.

```ml
(* direct style *)
print(add(5, 3))                  (* 8 *)

(* continuation-passing style *)
add(5, 3, print)                  (* 8 *)
```

> Expressing code in this form makes a number of things explicit which are implicit in direct style. These include: procedure returns, which become apparent as calls to a continuation; intermediate values, which are all given names; order of argument evaluation, which is made explicit; and tail calls, which simply call a procedure with the same continuation, unmodified, that was passed to the caller.

**you've probably used continuations before**

If you've ever run into someone saying "callback", what they really mean is continuation.

*"When the button is clicked, **continue** the program with `event => ...`"* -

```js
document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener("click", event => {
  console.log("this code runs inside a continuation!")
})
```

```html
<button id="foo">click me</button>
```

*"When the file contents are read, **continue** the program with `(err, data) => ...`"* -

```js
import { readFile } from 'fs';

readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: u got any useful links to learn cps?? I don't get the wikipedia one

Comment: where are you getting stuck? you may need to spend some time with the wikipedia examples and work through them slowly, and multiple times. i provided an update to this answer that walks you through the process. let me know if you have follow up questions, i'm happy to assist.